# convert specific bits of a QByteArray to int,float double etc

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I have a QByteArray, inside the QByteArray are multiple values of diferent datatypes which I want to extract. The difficulty by that is, that the values are in an defined length of x-bits, and they have a defined start position (also in bits).

eg: an int8 is stored inside the QByteArray from bit nr. 4 (of the first byte) to bit nr. 12 (inside the second byte).

On the Qt-wiki side i found a method to disassemble a byteArray into a bit array: https://wiki.qt.io/Working_with_Raw_Data

So i'm cutting my bits out of the byte array like that:

```
QByteArray MyCutter::cutMessage(qint32 bitStart, qint32 bitLength)
{
    qDebug() << mBuffer;
    QBitArray bits(mBufferLen * 8);
    for(quint32 i=0; i<mBufferLen; ++i)
    {
        for(quint32 b=0; b<8; b++)
        {
            bits.setBit(i*8 +b, mBuffer.at(i) & (1<<(7-b)));
        }
    }

    qDebug() << bits;
    QByteArray bytes;
    //round up to the next n*8 length of a byte: (length + y) = x*8
    qint32 bitLengthWithZeros = (bitLength + (8 - 1)) & ~(8 - 1);
    bytes.resize(bitLengthWithZeros/8);
    bytes.fill(0);

    for(qint32 b=bitStart ,c=0; b<(bitStart + bitLength); b++, c++)
    {
        bytes[c/8] = (bytes.at(c/8) | ((bits.testBit(b)?1:0)<<(7-b%8)));
    }
    qDebug() << bytes;
    return bytes.data();
}
```

This is working fine so far - I can cut my ByteArray into any other.
The Problem is to convert the values into int/float/doubles, and to be more specific into signed values.

To convert i've tried two things:
QByteArray::toHex().toLong(nullptr, 16) ... toLong/toLongLong etc. This is working, but only returns me the UNSIGNED value of the QByteArray. If I'm cutting the mBuffer with the function `MyCutter::cutMessage`, like the excample above, from the 4. bit to the 12. (which is also 0xFF) im getting 255 as signed int! And that's wrong?

On the other side I've tried to convert it with QStremData:

```
QDataStream stream(mBuffer);
stream.setByteOrder(QDataStream::LittleEndian);
qint64 result;
stream >> result;
qDebug() << QString::number(result,16);
qDebug() << QString::number(result);
```

mBuffer are the raw data. If im putting `"\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF"` insde mBuffer, the printed value is -1 which is correct.

```
QByteArray h = cutMessage(0,8);
qDebug() << h.toHex().toLongLong(nullptr, 16);
QDataStream stream2(h);
stream2.setByteOrder(QDataStream::LittleEndian);
qint64 result2;
stream2 >> result2;
qDebug() << QString::number(result2,16);
qDebug() << QString::number(result2);
```

Converting the cut-Message with the code block above is always returning me "0".

So without cutting, the interpretation of the whole QByteArray is correct, but if I'am cutting something off it's returning me always the unsigned value, or "0".

Somehow I'am loosing some information while the transformation into QBitArray and vice versa.

Hopefully my explanations are understandable ;)

Comment: I'm not sure how this framework handles all these conversions, but if you just plop `0xFF` into a 32 bit integer to get `0x000000FF`, then that is indeed interpreted as `255`. As opposed to a signed 8 bit integer where `0xFF` is `-1`. That's because of the way how two's complement works: the first bit of the `FF` is counted as `-128` in the `0xFF`, but in `0x000000FF` it's not the most significant bit of the number, so it counts as positive `128`.

Comment: Indeed, I didn't thought about that, and you are right!
So, the problem is not the cutting, but the container/datatype it's stored afterwards.

Comment: You try to read a 64-bit int from a 8-bit buffer. That won't work. QDataStream checks if there's enough data, and returns 0 if not ([source](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/corelib/serialization/qdatastream.cpp.html#_ZN11QDataStreamrsERx))